# Going through a hard ordeal to achieve something important?

Tags: expressions

What is a strong expression for someone going though a hard ordeal to achieve something important? For example a mother who has lost her children will _______ to get them back.

Comment: "go to hell and back"

Comment: *...do anything...*

Comment: walk through fire

Comment: go through fire and water

Comment: with a slight modification: will get them back by any means necessary.  (Think of Malcolm X.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are three fitting idioms for "*going through a hard ordeal to achieve something important*":

> **1**) [**move heaven and earth**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/move+heaven+and+earth) *idiom*: Exert the utmost effort, as in I'd *move heaven and earth* to get an apartment here. This hyperbolic expression was first recorded in 1792.
>
> **2**) [**fight tooth and nail**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fight+tooth+and+nail) *idiom*: Engage in vigorous combat or make a strenuous effort, using all one's resources. For example, I'm going to *fight tooth and nail* for that promotion. This expression, with its allusion to biting and scratching, was first recorded in 1576.
>
> **3**) [**go through hell**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+through+hell) *idiom*: to have a very unpleasant experience, especially one that lasts for a long period of time. The poor woman's been *going through hell* over the last few months, not knowing whether her son was alive or dead.

(All linked definitions from *The Free Dictionary*)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did that by including the link.

Comment: No, *EL&U* prefers direct quotations be explicitly credited, plus links become obsolete. *Move heaven and earth* is a good suggestion, but you could improve the answer by including supporting quotations for *all* your suggestions, w/links, citations, examples of usage - these will increase your up-votes (usually).

Comment: Thanks.  As a newbie around here, I have a lot to absorb.

Comment: A great way to learn is to click 'edit' on posts you like the formatting of. Later, click it to see what Eva (hopefully) has done to yours for how to do it in the future.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I appreciate the help in fitting into the culture!

Answer (score 15):

One that comes to mind that fits right into your sentences is to [*move mountains*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/move+mountains) (Farlex Free Dictionary).

> **move mountains**
>
> 1. if someone or someone's beliefs or feelings can move mountains, they can achieve something that is very difficult. *If faith can move mountains, we'll win the Cup.*
> 2. if you would move mountains for someone, they are so important to you that you would do anything to please them. *He'd move mountains for her but she treats him like dirt.*

Answer (score 13):

She will be disposed to go ***[through hell and high water](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/through+hell+and+high+water)*** to get them back:

> - Fig. through all sorts of severe difficulties. (Use hell with caution.)
>
>   - You'll have to go through hell and high water to accomplish your goal, but it'll be worth it.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: To *be disposed* in English is not  exactly the same as *disposta* in Italian. *è disposta a tutto* means someone is "willing, desperate to do anything". You wouldn't normally say someone is *disposed to do anything*. (this might make for an interesting question on EL&U....)

Comment: Disposed - having made preparations; "prepared to take risks". http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disposed

Comment: "I am disposed to take a risk", meaning I am inclined, of a disposition to take a risk, is not exactly the same as the Italian *disposta a fare tutto*, which is what I think you meant to say. And I would use the present tense rather than pure future. But as I said previously, this could be a nice question for ELU, I don't think the English *dispose* has the same nuance as the Italian *disporre*, and WR seems to agree with me http://www.wordreference.com/iten/disposto

Comment: This is the nuance that the Italian '*essere disposto a*' has: Disposed:
adjective UK   ( formal )
***be disposed to do sth***
*to be willing or likely to do something:*
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/britannico/disposed

Comment: Of course you can be "disposed to do something", I'm saying that a person wouldn't normally say: *“I will be disposed to do anything* (i.e. come hell and high water), *in order to get my child"*. The idiom is fine, perfect. I only wanted to gently point out that the verb, *disposed*, isn't the most appropriate. Call it collocation if you must. I would opt for *is determined to go through....* I hope I've made myself perfectly clear. Anyway, in the end, I guess we agree to disagree.

Comment: +1 61, for the phrase *go through hell and high water*, but respectfully, from the perspective of AmE, Mari-Lou is correct as to the issue of *disposed*, which in this context lacks the sense of *implacable determination* you'd want to match your phrase GTHaHW.

Comment: @LittleEva - I do appreciate your comments. I think that the 'implacable determination' is conveyed by the idiomatic expression itself. *Disposed to* just means *willing to* . I know it is not a common expression and rather formal in usage (so not a perfect fit here) but a good occasion to ponder on an  *unconventional* usage. :))

Answer (score 6):

You're asking for an expression describing an extreme sacrifice in exchange for great reward. One common such expression is *to sell your soul*, suggesting you are willing to give up your own freedom and life for your goal. This often has negative connotations and is frequently related to material gains, but could just as easily describe the desparation a mother feels searching for her lost child. In fact, many folk tales and fantasies depict a character quite literally exchanging their soul or the essence of their being with a godlike figure for some power, wealth, or the return of a lost loved one.

Another expression is the willingness to *go to the ends of the earth* searching for your goal. This alludes to the archaic belief that the world has edge-like boundaries far beyond the realm of experience most people can claim to know. Being willing to travel to the ends of the earth, therefore, implies being willing to leave your life and the whole known world behind, likely spending the rest of your days in search of your goal.

Answer (score 2):

If the important thing to be achieved is spending time with someone with whom you're infatuated, then you might say that you would [crawl on your hands and knees over broken glass just to do X](http://dictionary.babylon.com/crawl_on_my_hands_and_knees_over_broken_glass_just_to_see_her_photo/) for/with that person:

> do anything to be closer to her, worship the ground she walks on I'm so in love I'd crawl on my hands and knees over miles of broken glass to see her photo.

-- From the Babylon online dictionary

Choosing X to be some utterly trifling and/or depraved activity can enhance the comic effect.

Answer (score 1):

**persevere:** to persist in an undertaking despite counter influences, opposition or discouragement.

Webster's New Collegiate

Comment: perseverance - steadfastness in doing something despite difficulty or delay in achieving success.

Answer (score 1):

[Stop at nothing](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stop+at+nothing) is a pretty solid option.

> Do everything in one's power, be prevented by no obstacle, as in She'll stop at nothing to get her revenge. This expression was first recorded in John Dryden's Aurengzebe (1676): "The World is made for the bold impious man; Who stops at nothing, seizes all he can."

Answer (score 0):

*Wrestle with the devil* is an expression that I've heard.

Comment: Provide some examples, with citations and links, if possible kimb, this will strengthen what is otherwise an appropriate suggestion. And welcome to *EL&U*.

Answer (score 0):

The popularity of the movie *The Shawshank Redemption* has caused a line to enter the common vernacular: "...who crawled through a river of shit, and came out clean on the other side."

Reading your question, that line was the first thing to come to my mind.

It can be modified to fit grammatically into different sentences and still maintain its meaning.

The woman who ultimately saved her children crawled through a river of shit, but the story has a happy ending.

Spoiler alert: [from The Shawshank Redemption](https://youtu.be/PsqPirtOV6w?t=42s)

Answer (score -3):

*[Running the gauntlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_the_gauntlet)*, you could say.

Comment: It's just a link senyb, give us more than that and your suggestion is more likely to receive positive votes.