# Is there an idiomatic way to say that it took a lot of time and effort for someone to do something?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Is there an idiomatic way to say that it took a lot of time and effort for someone to do something?

**Example:** you ask someone a question to which they are reluctant to give an answer, but eventually, and especially after a lot of struggle, they do. And now you want to say something like "oh my god he went through hell to answer that (which isn't befitting of course)". What should we say?

Comment: There's  probably a few..like "beating around the bush"

Comment: @Rattler thanks. Would it sound odd to say "it killed him to answer that question"?

Comment: 'Moved mountains' means it took much effort. If it took *me* that much effort, it was 'like pulling teeth' to get him to talk.

Comment: I'm not sure how wide-spread that  idiom is, but for me it would be understandable.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a million guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an idiom available, that is exactly opposite to "Cake walk" or "Child's play"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373768/is-there-an-idiom-available-that-is-exactly-opposite-to-cake-walk-or-childs) 'no small feat' / 'a herculean task' / 'an uphill battle/fight/struggle' / 'a hard/tough/difficult nut to crack' / 'like pulling teeth' / 'a tough row to hoe' ...

Comment: And [Going through a hard ordeal to achieve something important](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262838/going-through-a-hard-ordeal-to-achieve-something-important/262841#262841) ([having to] move Heaven and Earth / fight tooth and nail / move mountains / go through hell and high water / persevere ... A Sisyphean task.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes all of them fit the situation I was trying to describe, particularly "pulling teeth". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adjective "laborious" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/laborious?q=laborious).

- That was laborious.

An expression would be "to move Heaven and Earth".

- We had to **move Heaven and Earth** to get permission from the authorities.

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the idiom **went the extra mile**?

From M-W:

> **[go the extra mile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20the%20extra%20mile)**: to do more than one is required to do, e.g., she's always willing to go the extra mile to help a friend.

From Cambridge:

> **[go the extra mile](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mile?q=go%20the%20extra%20mile)**: to make more effort than is expected of you, e.g., to be successful, you need to be willing to go the extra mile for your customers.